# "Reflect" as a noun

Tags: nouns, lyrics

The song *For Marlon* by Soko has the lyrics

> And it's been raining for 3 days straight
>
> As a sad reflect of my sorry state

Can you use *reflect* as a noun (instead of *reflection*) or is Soko using a poetic licence? In general, is it sometimes okay to drop the suffix `-ion` in nouns?

Comment: To me, that's an invention. (Perhaps the same songwriter would say that it is an "*invent*".) Normally you would use *reflection*.

Comment: In response to the second part of the question, no, it is not generally acceptable to drop the `-ion` suffix from a noun.  That is, if the result is a word at all, it is rarely, if ever, synonymous with the original noun.  Sometimes, as in your example, it is a verb related to the noun.  Other times (***nation***, ***fashion***, ***hellion***), not.

Comment: that usage probably falls under the poetic license idea; I.e. You can twist a phrase up as much as you want in poetry to elicit the desired effect in meter, rhyme and tone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun *reflect* has a long history. Citations from *Oxford English Dictionary* go back to 1594 and the most recent quote is from 1996:

> B. Siegel *World of Autistic Child* (1998) ii. xii. 298
>
> Lack of enthusiasm for a new job or any new setting is common in autistic people, and may mostly be a reflect of their dislike of things that are unfamiliar.

The meaning is the same as *reflection*, sense 1 and 3, *OED*, which I assume you're familiar with and can get from this example and the one you cite.

English won't break if you do drop the -ion from nouns. What to wonder is will anyone else follow you in doing so. Language is a creative medium, like paint or clay. English  survived all of Shakespeare's and others' coinings and "violations".

*Invent* was used as a noun in the early 17th century but it is not anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am indeed familiar with the meaning of *reflection* (that was a fair assumpt).

Comment: Well  if you like the answer and another doesn't come along you can always make this one your select.